# Trying to use MySQL fields as a restriction for data

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, dreamweaver, restrictions

I'll try to make this as concise as possible, but any help is greatly appreciated.  My skill level is slightly above minimal in PHP/MySQL so I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 to try to get my site up and running.  I need to be able to restrict data returned from the database to the user that created the entry, so I wanted to reuse the login information to track who was inputting data.

```html
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_UserLoginForm = "SELECT * FROM users";
$UserLoginForm = mysql_query($query_UserLoginForm, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_UserLoginForm = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserLoginForm);
$totalRows_UserLoginForm = mysql_num_rows($UserLoginForm);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['UserLogin'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['UserLogin'];
  $password=$_POST['UserPass'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "main.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "UserRegistration.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
  
  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT user_login, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_login=%s AND user_pass=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 
   
  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";
    
 if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  </head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="180" height="90" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #C6D580; display:block;" /></a> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="character_list.php">My Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="UserLoginForm" id="UserLoginForm">
      <table width="200" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Username:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="UserLogin"></label>
          <input name="UserLogin" type="text" id="UserLogin" size="28"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span id="sprypassword1">
            <label for="UserPass"></label>
            <input name="UserPass" type="password" id="UserPass" size="28">
          <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="UserLoginSubmit" id="UserLoginSubmit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table><input name="user_status" type="hidden" value="">
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="UserRegistration.php">Register</a></p>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Please login to proceed</h1>
    <p>This is a testing site only, no guarantees of security so watch yourself</p>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>This .footer contains the declaration position:relative; to give Internet Explorer 6 hasLayout for the .footer and cause it to clear correctly. If you're not required to support IE6, you may remove it.</p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($UserLoginForm);
?>
```

So the above is the login information.  The database is rpg_test and the table is users, the relevant fields I'm looking to track down are user_id and user_login.  As you'd expect, user_id is an integer primary key and user_login the alphanumeric username.  The page uses this to login to the other pages and seems to hold onto a variable that includes a valid username.

This is an example of one of the pages of a user that's already logged in:

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/DLP_RPG.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
 
  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "0";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_UserLoginForm = "SELECT * FROM users";
$UserLoginForm = mysql_query($query_UserLoginForm, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_UserLoginForm = mysql_fetch_assoc($UserLoginForm);
$totalRows_UserLoginForm = mysql_num_rows($UserLoginForm);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_PlaySystem = "SELECT play_systems.play_system FROM play_systems";
$PlaySystem = mysql_query($query_PlaySystem, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_PlaySystem = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlaySystem);
$totalRows_PlaySystem = mysql_num_rows($PlaySystem);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_characters = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE characters.character_owner";
$characters = mysql_query($query_characters, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_characters = mysql_fetch_assoc($characters);
$totalRows_characters = mysql_num_rows($characters);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  </head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="" alt="Insert Logo Here" name="Insert_logo" width="180" height="90" id="Insert_logo" style="background-color: #C6D580; display:block;" /></a> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
    
      <li><a href="#">My Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="new_character1.php">New Character</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a></p><br> I should come up with a way to show this only if you're logged in<br>

    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>List of characters</h1>
    <p>This page should list all of your characters, and just your characters.</p>
    <p>Edit and delete buttons should be included.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Type:</td>
        <td>System:</td>
        <td>Owner:</td>
      </tr>
      <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row_characters['character_name1']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_characters['character_occupation']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_characters['play_system']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_characters['character_owner']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_characters = mysql_fetch_assoc($characters)); ?>
    </table>
<!-- end .content --></div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($UserLoginForm);

mysql_free_result($PlaySystem);

mysql_free_result($characters);
?>
```

What I wanted to be able to do is have the "Owner" field in the html table that shows the characters will only show the characters owned by the person that made them.  I ideally would restrict it by the user_id field being equal to whatever the login tracking uses to access the page.  I'm guessing it's some kind of persistent variable that I can hopefully call up and insert as data when updating the table.

Is there such a variable?  I keep seeing $UserName and other things but maybe I'm going in circles.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  From what I can find on the site I need to use a session variable.

I did a print_r($SESSION) of one of the pages and it gives:

Array ( [PrevUrl] => /rpg/character_list.php [MM_Username] => joecook [MM_UserGroup] => )

The login for MM-Username is what would fit into my user_login field, but the table below shows that the field being used by the table is user_id.  I'm logged in as user_id=2, and I only want to see the entries that relate to me.

```html
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Type:</td>
        <td>System:</td>
        <td>Owner:</td>
      </tr>
              <tr>
          <td>Fuzz Duck</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Palladium Megaverse</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>another heresy test for owner</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>Heresy Game Engine</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Another Heresy test</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>Heresy Game Engine</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
            </table>
```

This is the previous form that populates the above table with data if that helps:

```html
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Starting a new character</h1>
    <p>The first thing to do when starting a new character is to select the play system from a drop down list</p>
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="PlaySystemForm" id="PlaySystemForm">
      <table width="500" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th width="129" scope="row">System:</th>
          <td width="355"><label for="play_system2"></label>
            <select name="play_system" id="play_system2">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_PlaySystem['play_system']?>"><?php echo $row_PlaySystem['play_system']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_PlaySystem = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlaySystem));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($PlaySystem);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($PlaySystem, 0);
   $row_PlaySystem = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlaySystem);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Name:</th>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
          <label for="character_name"></label>
          <input name="character_name" type="text" id="character_name" size="25" maxlength="128">
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg">Minimum number of characters not met.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Type:</th>
          <td><label for="character_type1"></label>
            <select name="character_type1" id="character_type1">
              <?php
do {  
?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row_character_type['character_type1_id']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_character_type['character_type1_id'], $row_PlaySystem['play_system']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_character_type['character_type1']?></option>
              <?php
} while ($row_character_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($character_type));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($character_type);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($character_type, 0);
   $row_character_type = mysql_fetch_assoc($character_type);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input name="CharacterOwner" type="hidden" id="CharacterOwner" value="<?php echo $row_UserLoginForm['user_id']; ?>">
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="NewCharacterSubmit" id="NewCharacterSubmit" value="Create character">
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="PlaySystemForm">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition to your query, ie.

```
WHERE characters.character_owner = users.user_id
```

Since you are only storing the `user_login`/(`$_SESSION['MM_Username']`) and not the `user_id`, you would need to use a subquery to get the `user_id`. Try changing -

```
$query_characters = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE characters.character_owner";
```

to

```
$query_characters = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE characters.character_owner = 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = '{$_SESSION['MM_Username']}')";
```

user_login

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much.  Now I need to figure out why it's not inputting the correct user_id on the input form and I'll call that page a success.  Again, thank you so much.